# Set background for each tab bar item

Tags: ios, xcode, background, uitabbar

I have struggled several hours now trying to add an uniqe image (because i want the tab separators to show up correctly with no separators to the far left and right) for each item in my UITabBar.

The following code I have in my app delegate displays the items in a strange way at the bottom.. Also would want to remove the title labels. What would be the correct approach? This is driving me crazy..

[Image of my tabbar](http://tinypic.com/r/4uuhwj/6)

```
UIImage *selectedImage0   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-tab-active"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-tab"];

UIImage *selectedImage1   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"guide-tab-active"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"guide-tab"];

UIImage *selectedImage2   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search-tab-active"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search-tab"];

UIImage *selectedImage3   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites-tab-active"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites-tab"];

UIImage *selectedImage4   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locations-tab-active"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locations-tab"];

// The Tab Bar
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The titles and images of tab items should come from the content controllers assigned to each of the tabs, not from the tab bar controller. It looks like you have the ones you're creating in the app delegate as well as ones that belong to the individual controllers, and that's why you're getting overlapping images and titles (the default string for a tab bar item is the title of the controller assigned to that tab).